# Select list height 100 percent inside div

Tags: html, css

I have this select list inside of a div and I want to set the height to 100% and not the size number (size=10) of the select.
How can I do it?

My code:

```
<div style="top:18%; left:5%; width:25%; height:40%; background: rgba(0,204,0,1); position:absolute; border:#0000FF solid 1px;">
  <table width="100%" height="10%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td align="left" valign="middle">Header</td>
    </tr>
  </table>  
  <div>
  <form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="">
      <select name="selectList" id="selectList" size="10" style="width:100%; height:50%; overflow-y:scroll;">
        <?php
        $qry= pg_query($dbconn,"select * from table") or die(pg_last_error($dbconn));
        while($row_qry = pg_fetch_assoc($qry)){
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row_qry['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row_qry['name']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
      </select>   
  </form>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want `select` to be 100% height of the screen or of the parent element?

Comment: 90% because the table is already 10%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give height to HTML and body to 100%.
Your code is not properly nested
Here is working code

```
 <html>
   <head>
     <style>
       html, body {height: 100%;}
     </style>
   </head>
 <body>
    <div style="top:18%; left:5%; width:25%; height:40%; background: rgba(0,204,0,1); position:absolute; border:#0000FF solid 1px;">
       <table width="100%" height="10%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="middle">Header</td>
          </tr>
      </table>  
      <form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="" style="height: 90%">
          <select name="selectList" id="selectList" size="10" style="width:100%; height:100%; overflow-y:scroll;">
              <option value=""></option>
          </select>   
        </form>  
       </div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: The form height was missing for my needs! Many thanks!